# IF - ELSE IF - ELSE Structure in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Requirement :**

If the string in cell A1 contains "abc" as part of the string

Then assign value "Green"

Else if the string in cell A1 contains "xyz" as part of the string

Then assign value "Yellow"

Else

Assign value "Red"

**I tried this :**

`=IF(FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"abc","~",1))<>"#VALUE!", "Green", IF(FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"xyz","~",1))<>"#VALUE!", "Yellow", "Red"))`

It works if first IF is True in other cases it gives #VALUE! as output.

Can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When `FIND` returns `#VALUE!`, it is an error, not a string, so you can't compare `FIND(...)` with `"#VALUE!"`, you need to check if `FIND` returns an error with `ISERROR`. Also `FIND` can work on multiple characters.

So a simplified and working version of your formula would be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("abc",A1))=FALSE, "Green", IF(ISERROR(FIND("xyz",A1))=FALSE, "Yellow", "Red"))
```

Or, to remove the double negations:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("abc",A1)), IF(ISERROR(FIND("xyz",A1)), "Red", "Yellow"),"Green")
```

Answer (score 13):

```
=IF(CR<=10, "RED", if(CR<50, "YELLOW", if(CR<101, "GREEN")))
```

`CR = ColRow (Cell)` This is an example. In this example when value in Cell is less then or equal to 10 then RED word will appear on that cell. In the same manner other if conditions are true if first if is false.

Answer (score 1):

Say P7 is a Cell then you can use the following Syntex to check the value of the cell and assign appropriate value to another cell based on this following nested if:

```
=IF(P7=0,200,IF(P7=1,100,IF(P7=2,25,IF(P7=3,10,IF((P7=4),5,0)))))
```