# How to use IF with And and OR in Excell?

Tags: excel, logical-operators

I am using a FIFA 8 dataset for a project. There are various fields like age, rating, value and wage. Now I want to make a column of whether the player should be bought or not. I want to make this in Excel. I want to use a condition such as:

```
IF(Age<30 & Rating >90 & Value>100) OR If (Age<25 & Rating >85 & Value >70 ) then buy
```

How can I use this kind of different situations in one formula in Excel?

Comment: So, Excel or R? Quite different IMHO.

Comment: Anyone will do.

Comment: Mixing two unrelated programming languages in one answer list would be confusing. I removed the R option from question since all the answers so far deal with Excel. If you want a solution in R, please ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

For Excel you can try following formula.

- Column A is Age
- Column B is Rating
- Column C is Value

`=IF(OR(AND(A2>30,B2>90,C2>100),AND(A2<25,B2>85,C2>70)),"buy","not buy")`

Or visit https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2523-excel-if-and-or-not.html

Answer (score 1):

Your original formula can be converted into Excel without too much trouble:

```
IF(Age<30 & Rating >90 & Value>100) OR IF (Age<25 & Rating >85 & Value >70)
```

This becomes:

```
=OR(AND(Age<30, Rating>90, Value>100), AND(Age<25, Rating>85, Value >70)
```

Of course, you would need to replace the named variables with actual cell references, but for the purpose of an easy to read answer, it seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow explains the correct method for IF - ELSE - IF Structure in Excel here

[IF - ELSE IF - ELSE Structure in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531531/if-else-if-else-structure-in-excel)

> When FIND returns #VALUE!, it is an error, not a string, so you can't compare FIND(...) with "#VALUE!", you need to check if FIND returns an error with ISERROR. Also FIND can work on multiple characters.

So a simplified and working version of your formula would be: